# ConcurrentModificationException Room DataBase

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using RoomDatabase using Coroutine, but always i have crash in my application when inserting data, here is my code.

```
       if (attandenceListOffline.isNotEmpty()) {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
                val localCopy = attandenceListOffline
                roomViewModel.addAttandance(localCopy)
            }
        }
```

And this is Source code inside RoomViewModel:

```
    suspend fun addAttandance( data: List<AttandanceEntity>)  {
        userRepository.insertAttandance(data)
    }
```

and this is declaration of the method inside DAO:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun saveAttandance(exo: List<AttandanceEntity>)
```

I tried to change type of attandenceListOffline to 'CopyOnWriteArrayList' But always i recieve crash:
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$It

I tried to change type of attandenceListOffline to CopyOnWriteArray but always the same error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-8
Process: com.vyzyo.vyzyoschool, PID: 29538
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
    at androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insert()
```

Comment: Check the stack trace you get with the `ConcurrentModificationException`, may be the list causing it is a totally different one that you expect.

Comment: Please do not post stack traces in comments as it makes them pretty hard to read. Please edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentModificationException always means that you're trying to modify a list while working on it at the same time.  You're trying to insert a list of AttendanceEntries to a list of AttendanceEntries.  It has nothing to do with your coroutine.  Try making a copy of your list, then add it to the copy, then update the attandenceListOffline with the copy.

Comment: I'm making copy using this pseudo code:
  val localCopy = attandenceListOffline
                roomViewModel.addAttandance(localCopy)

Answer (score 0):

`val localCopy = attandenceListOffline` does not make a copy.
They are both pointers that point to the same object.

When that object is mutated, you will see the CME.

To make a (shallow) copy, use `.toList()`.

---

But the problem of concurrent read and write still exists. It is simply moved from reading during the insertion to reading during copying.

If `attandenceListOffline` is modified by multiple threads, you (should) already have some synchronization mechanism, use that in the read as well.

If `attandenceListOffline` is only modified in the main thread and that block of code is in the main thread, you can write:

```kotlin
if (attandenceListOffline.isNotEmpty()) {
    val localCopy = attandenceListOffline.toList()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        roomViewModel.addAttandance(localCopy)
    }
}
```

---

BTW `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch` is a code smell that runs afoul of structured concurrency.

Comment: Thank you for your response, about your last comment "BTW CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch is a code smell that runs afoul of structured concurrency" how can i fix it?

Comment: You should find a scope to attach that job's lifecycle to. If your code *should* (a rare case) be fire-and-forget, use `GlobalScope` for that.